# Potentiometer tension equation computation

Tags: circuit-analysis, potentiometer

I am struggling to understand how to compute a specific, simple, equation relative to potentiometers. Given the image below:

[image]

I do not understand how to get to the second equation, i.e., the case in which the potentiometer is not an open load.

I managed to easily verify the OL case.
In the second scenario, I applied the first Kirchhoff's law to the node between R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub>, but I ended up with a V<sub>out</sub> = ƒ(V<sub>in</sub>) much more complicated (and, presumably, wrong) than the one reported in the figure, which assume is true, as confirmed by multiple online sources.

As I did not find a demonstration about how to get to that simple equation, I am asking for some help.

Comment: You just find the equivalent resistance of R2||R3 and redraw the schematic with that. Or more generally, just do KVL on the entire circuit without trying to simplify resistor combinations since real problems won't always simplify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally, both cases are [voltage dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) with a difference in the division ratio due to the changing \$R_3\$ (presumably the potentiometer mentioned). The second case is the same as the first, except that \$R_2\$ is replaced with

$$R_2 \parallel R_3 = \frac{R_2 R_3}{R_2 + R_3}$$

since you can no longer ignore the non-infinite \$R_3\$ (the two resistances are in parallel, which is what the \$\parallel\$ symbol means).

The equation is therefore:

$$V_\text{out} = V_\text{in}\frac{R_2 \parallel R_3}{R_1 + R_2 \parallel R_3} = V_\text{in}\frac{\frac{R_2 R_3}{R_2 + R_3}}{R_1 + \frac{R_2 R_3}{R_2 + R_3}}$$

which can be simplified as:

$$V_\text{out} = V_\text{in}\frac{R_2 R_3}{R_1(R_2+R_3) + R_2 R_3} = V_\text{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1\left(\frac{R_2}{R_3}+1\right) + R_2}$$

as given. The advantage of rewriting the equation this way (so \$R_3\$ only appears once) is that it is easier to see what happens as \$R_3\$ reaches an extreme value.

Notice that

$$\lim_{R_3 \to \infty} V_\text{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1\left(\frac{R_2}{R_3}+1\right) + R_2} = V_\text{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

(i.e. the first case) since the \$R_2/R_3\$ term goes to 0 as \$R_3\$ increases to \$\infty\$.

Notice also that $$\lim_{R_3 \to 0} V_\text{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1\left(\frac{R_2}{R_3}+1\right) + R_2} = 0$$

since the \$R_2/R_3\$ term becomes infinite, resulting in an infinite denominator that causes the fraction to go to 0. This makes sense, as \$R_3 = 0\$ is shorting \$V_\text{out}\$.

Comment: You've done a yeoman's job showing traditional algebra and a few good implications to consider as validating that the result does the right thing at the two extremes. But how is it that \$R_3\$ modifies only the denominator in the original equation and, just then, still only by an added term of \$\frac{R_1\,R_2}{R_3}\$? Gaining some intuition there might be useful. Why should the term be the product of the two initial resistors divided by the third? What's going on? It's the kind of question I feel one needs to get into practice asking themselves. Answers can lead to improved vision.

Comment: I'm not complaining about your answer. I'm giving it +1 as the more complete of the two so far. And it is good. Don't get me wrong. I'm just thinking it is also good to isolate a term and explain it's addition into the denominator. What is the added term describing? What is its meaning?

Comment: @periblepsis I've edited my answer to provide some additional commentary which hopefully addresses your suggestions.

Comment: No. Not really, yet. Or I'm missing seeing what I'm looking for. The original equation can be re-written as \$\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2+\delta}\$ where \$\delta=\frac{R_1\,R_2}{R_3}\$. \$0\le \delta\le\infty\$ is the addition of a new term in the divisor, modifying it. How and why does this new term isolatable so as to ***only*** modify the divisor? How can one identify exactly what this new term describes? (If anything?) Or is the term merely the result of algebraic manipulation without any "meaning" to give it? I like to isolate terms and then ask such questions.

Comment: @periblepsis I suppose the insight would be that \$R_3\$ cannot increase the division ratio, only decrease it.

Comment: Now that's moving in the right direction, I think!!! Given that obvious qualitative observation, is there any added insight that might, without the traditional algebra but some new insight about that circumstance, lead one to the exact form of term? By this, I mean, thinking like Newton about G m1 m2 / r^2. He felt that increasing either mass should increase the force. So it must be a product there. Etc. One can move from qualitative intuition towards an expression... Why is there a product of R1 and R2? Why does increasing either one of them work like that?

Comment: @periblepsis \$R_2 \parallel R_3\$ can also be re-written so that \$R_3\$ only appears in the denominator, leading to a similar insight that putting a resistor in parallel with another resistor can only decrease the equivalent resistance. That, coupled with the voltage divider equation, would allow you to observe without algebra that \$R_3\$ can only decrease the division ratio. Do you have an answer to your question in mind that you are trying to lead me to, or are you trying to see if any such insight exists?

Comment: I think the person asking their question already has their answer and I am not sure they are ready for my hand-waving. I'm quite happy with what you wrote for them. There is something more. (Almost always is something more, to be honest.) But I'm happy leaving this as a dangling question. And yes, I think you touched closely.

Comment: @periblepsis There is no need to have a dangling question on a Q&A site. I encourage you to post it as a question. If you already know a good answer then you can answer your own question, otherwise the rest of the community can provide answer(s).

Comment: @periblepsis you should leave your (as yet) unknown thoughts as an answer so that others can benefit. TBH I have no idea what you are on about but, leaving an answer will reveal that.

Comment: @periblepsis: You're making a mountain out of a molehill. Both Null and Andyaka answered the question completely and succinctly. This is distracting to both answers and the ability of the OP to have clarity

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments, and especially thanks @Null for the answer, which is really clear. It's always a pleasure to receive so much detailing in the explanations!

Comment: I do not know if that is against the rule or the code of conduct of the website, but in case I still have a doubt may I integrate this question? The point is that your explanation is clear, but now I still do not understand why my equations led to a more complex (and probably wrong) result. Given the amount of variables and constant I'd need to write, I do not think leveraging this comment section would fit best.

Comment: @Jetboy Happy to help. If you have a follow-up question please post a new one (and link to this question if necessary).

Comment: Okay, thank you. As soon as I get the time to properly format it, I'll post a new question. If it does not bother you, I'll may update you here when that happens. Besides, I am think of using that same image above as a context reference, again I hope that is not an issue

Comment: @Jetboy Sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

> *I do not understand how to get to the second equation*

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{This is the only question raised by the OP when I made my answer}}}$$

With \$R_3\$ in parallel with \$R_2\$ your top formula becomes this: -

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}\hspace{0.2cm} = \hspace{0.2cm}\dfrac{R_2||R_3}{R_1 +R_2||R_3}\hspace{0.2cm} = \hspace{0.2cm}\dfrac{\frac{R_2\cdot R_3}{R_2+R_3}}{R_1 +\frac{R_2\cdot R_3}{R_2+R_3}}\hspace{0.2cm}
=\hspace{0.2cm}\dfrac{R_2\cdot R_3}{R_1\cdot R_2+R_1\cdot R_3+R2\cdot R_3}
\hspace{0.2cm}$$
$$=\hspace{0.2cm}\dfrac{R_2}{R_1\cdot\frac{R_2}{R3}+R_1+R_2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your edit. The only edit to the question has been to add a paragraph break -- the OP hasn't raised any other question as you are implying.

Comment: I don't see any problem here @Null

Comment: *sigh* You never do. You are implying the OP has edited the question and at least partially invalidated your answer. Since the OP has not done so your edit is pointless and distracting commentary.

Comment: No, you are inferring that; I'm not implying that.

Comment: @Null I added the red box words to deter periblepsis from attempting to "coach me" down a blind alley (as he seems to have done in comments under your answer). I can't see any benefit from what he was saying and, to me, his musings offer no insight beyond what can be achieved by simply looking at the circuit diagram. My personal belief is that he should be encouraged to leave an answer because, as they stand, his comments are just time-wasting noise as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you @Andyaka, I upvoted your answer. And yes, it is clear. I was stuck approaching this computation in a wrong way, and could not wrap my head around from here. Thank you!